# Find alerts in SPO library using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, alert, csom

How can I find alerts set on my lists using CSOM?

If necessary, I have the alert GUID and I have the list GUID

```
Alert={391EDCAC-BDC0-4561-8E86-5291E3323CF8}

List={E613438C-0DF1-429B-9087-0D01D4E0ACBF}
```

How can I retrieve it and its properties?

1. It is not under `$List.EventReceivers` (collection is empty)
2. There is no `$List.Alerts` collection
3. The alert is not listed under `$ctx.Web.EventReceivers`, nor `$ctx.Site.EventReceivers`.
4. None of the properties under `_api/web/siteusers` seems to be related to alerts, so it looks like the alerts are not attached to the users.
5. `http://<Site>/_vti_bin/Alerts.asmx` tells me that it is for a local server, not for SharePoint Online.
6. I am aware of UI possibility "Manage my alerts". I did not manage to find where it pulls the alerts from.

The alerts must be located somewhere. Please help me find where.

Comment: Hi Grisha, Did you wind a way to pull these alerts from SPO?

Comment: No, I did not :(

Comment: @PradeepNulu I did find it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Years later,

alerts can be found at `$web.Alerts`

This applies not only for the alerts at the site level, but also for list alerts and even item alerts.

We live and learn :)

Comment: How can this be done for SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Hi @Steve. As long as you are using CSOM, you can find alerts as a collection on $web object:
$Alerts  = $ctx.Web.Alerts
$ctx.Load($Alerts)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()